# Swift Convert NSImage to NSdata without using NSBitmapImageFileType

Tags: swift, macos, mime-types, nsdata, nsimage

I want to convert `NSImage` to `NSdata` with it's own MIME file type. The problem with `NSBitmapImageRep` conversion is we have to represent it with anyone of file `NSBitmapImageFileType`, which I don't want to do it and I want to convert with my own MIME file type.

Comment: `TIFFRepresentation`? Or 64 base encoding?

Answer (score -3):

You can use any of the below code as per your requirement to convert image to nsdata

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image)
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 1.0)
```

Comment: It represents PNG and Jpeg file types. And my question is for NSImage not UIImage.